# Rails rake test:units failure - something deeper?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

disclaimer: I am just starting on rails.

I've installed Ruby 1.9.3 using rvm without options.

I am following the tutorial for the Agile Development on rails 4th ed book.
When I run rails rake test:units I get this error:

```
Ascended:store Ascended$ rake test:units --trace** Invoke test:units (first_time)

** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge 
** Execute db:test:load_schema
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute test:units
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /Users/Ascended/Ruby/store/test/unit/product_test.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tFID, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
/Users/Ascended/Ruby/store/test/unit/product_test.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected '['
  assert product.[:price].any?
                  ^
/Users/Ascended/Ruby/store/test/unit/product_test.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected '['
  asssert product.[:image_url].any?
                   ^
    from /Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/Ascended/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p12...]
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in `ruby'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:60:in `verbose'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:98:in `block in define'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

I don't believe that it is anything to do with the rails app itself, probably something about the environment and how the rake and ruby was installed, probably how rvm installed and is loading up ruby?

I installed xcode and Ruby without --ggc-clang (read that 1.9.3 doesn't need that option anymore)

I'm a bit lost - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ruby is telling you, I think you have a syntax error:

```
assert product.[:price].any?
```

Should be:

```
assert product[:price].any?
```

Comment: It still give me this error even with that mistake. /Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /Users/Ascended/Ruby/store/test/unit/product_test.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tFID, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)

Comment: You also need to fix it for `asssert product.[:image_url].any?`by removing the dot.

Comment: Also, you might have a syntax error on line 7, too. What does that line say?

Comment: assert product.error[:description]any?, I missed the period before any. Running rake again..

Comment: now it's giving me: /Users/Ascended/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing': undefined method `image' for #<Product:0x007fc05bbb6778> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Does your model for Product have the :image field defined? Didn't you mean :image_url?

Comment: that last one was an issue in my model, I named the validate :image rather than image_url. Now I have this error: `/Users/Ascended/Ruby/store/test/unit/product_test.rb:5:in '<class:ProductTest>': undefined method 'assert' for ProductTest:Class (NoMethodError)
 from /Users/Ascended/Ruby/store/test/unit/product_test.rb:3:in '<top (required)>'`
line 5 in product_test is `assert product.invalid?`

Comment: Are you sure that ProductTest extends Test::Unit::TestCase? You need that to get `assert` defined. Also, you showed line 5 but the error says its on line 3.

Comment: oh, line 3... that's `class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase`

Comment: oh so it should be: `class ProductTest < Test::Unit::TestCase`?

Comment: I can't help you out without more code. My guess here is that you are calling `assert` from within the scope of the ProductTest class, rather than from within a test_* method inside that class.

Comment: No, since class ActiveSupport::TestCase already [extends](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TestCase.html) Test::Unit::TestCase :)

Comment: Could it have anything to do with how i've setup rvm/ruby/rails?

Comment: Most likely not. As I said, my best guess is you are doing something like `class ProductTest; assert ... ; end` when you should put all your tests inside methods: `class ProductTest; def test_something; assert ...; end; end`

Comment: yep, I had a mistake in `def "some_test" do`. Rake runs fine now. Thanks a lot louism!